# Generate all longest common prefix between a list and all its own suffixes

Tags: algorithm

let `lcp` be a function of generating the number of longest common prefix between two lists.

for example `lcp [1;2;3;1;2] [1;2] = 2`.

---

For a given list, it has `n` non-empty suffixes, including itself.

For example,

all suffixes of [1;2;3] are:

[1;2;3]
[2;3]
[3]

---

The problem here is generating all the `lcp` between a `list` and `all its own suffixes`.

Here we are talking about list A and A's all suffixes. There are no list B existing.

for example, for list `[1;2;3]`, I want a list of values and each value is

`llcp [1;2;3] [1;2;3]`

`llcp [1;2;3] [2;3]`

`llcp [1;2;3] [3]`

respectively. i.e., the result should be [3;0;0]

---

It is straightforward to use brute-force, but it take `O(n^2)`.

How to do it in **O(n)**?

Don't use suffix tree or suffix array.

---

**edit**

I think it is definitely possible to do **O(n)**. I have not figured out fully yet, but I find something interesting.

For example, we have `[x1;x2;x3;x4;x5;x6]`, then its all suffixes are

`row1: [x1;x2;x3;x4;x5;x6]`

`row2: [x2;x3;x4;x5;x6]`

`row3: [x3;x4;x5;x6]`

`row4: [x4;x5;x6]`

`row5: [x5;x6]`

`row6: [x6]`

Our goal is to calculate

`lcp row1 row1` (obviously it is n)

`lcp row1 row2`

`lcp row1 row3`

`lcp row1 row4`

`lcp row1 row5`

`lcp row1 row6`

---

So let's try `lcp row1 row2` first.

If let's say `lcp row1 row2 = 3`, this means `x1=x2; x2=x3; x3=x4; x4<>x5`, right?

Then what we can get from the above comparisons?

we can know

- `x1 = x3; x2 = x4; x3 <> x5`, right? then immediately we get `lcp row1 row3 = 2`, right?
- `x1 = x4; x2 <> x5`, right? then immediately `lcp row1 row4 = 1`
- `x1 <> x5`, then immediately `lcp row1 row5 = 0`

And only `lcp row1 row6` is left to do.

The key here I guess is **equality is transferable and also inequality can be inducted via partial equality information**

Comment: What does Java tag has to do with a pretty algorithmic question?

Comment: @thermz to help getting more attentions? just in case a good java programmer who doesn't care about algorithm happens to know the solution for this problem?

Comment: I really doubt you can do this in `O(n)`. When iterating over the suffices, you drop the first element each time, but that is the most important element (as it is the "anchor" of the prefix). It seems that there is no relation between two consecutive lcp calls that you can exploit to get to linear time.

Comment: @Heuster I think it can do, I thought over several days, find something as possible hints, updating my edit now

Comment: It is only O(N²) in the worst case. But if, for example, x1 is unique, then no proper suffix can start with x1, hence lcp = 0 in 1 step. So in the best case it is O(N).

Comment: @Ingo Best case does not make much sense in algorithm design. Also I am talking about general case O(n) and even worst case still O(n)

Comment: @JacksonTale Sure, but clearly the worst case happens only for lists of the form [c,c,c,...]. The bigger the element type the less likely is it, that x2 = x1, x3 = x2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute z-function for the list(treating is like a string and each element as one character). Then the answer for the suffix starting at the i-th position is z(i). It should be easy to find z-function algorithm implementation in O(n).
Here is my O(n) implementation.

```
   public static List<Integer> getLcp(List<Integer> input) {
            Integer[] lcp = new Integer[input.size()];
            Arrays.fill(lcp, input.size());
            int left = 1;
            int right = -1;
            for (int pos = 1; pos < input.size(); pos++) {
                    if (pos <= right)
                            lcp[pos] = Math.min(lcp[pos - left], right - pos + 1);
                    else
                            lcp[pos] = 0;
                    while (pos + lcp[pos] < input.size() &&
                                    input.get(pos + lcp[pos]) == input.get(lcp[pos]))
                            lcp[pos]++;
                    if (pos + lcp[pos] - 1 > right) {
                            left = pos;
                            right = pos + lcp[pos] - 1;
                    }
            }
            return Arrays.asList(lcp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that this is possible to solve in O(n).
But you can make a good optimization.

I would propose something linke this:

- First get the maximal suffix of element 1 and 2
- Then get the maximal suffix between the previous result and element 3
- go on until you reach the end

In most cases the suffix should become a really short string after you have processed the first few elements, and then you don't have to compaare many chars.
The idea is that when element 1 and 2 have a n-long suffix the global suffix can maximal be n-long (but it can be shorter).

---

Edit:

Okay i think i understood your problem now :D
But i can't think of a O(n)-way.
Here is my best try (unfortunately in C#, because currently i have no java-IDE on this computer...)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("  ", llcp(new List<char> { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B' }).Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray()));

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static List<int> llcp(List<char> elements)
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < elements.Count; j++)
            if (i+j >= elements.Count || elements[i+j] != elements[j])
                break;
        result.Add(j);
    }
    return result;
}
//Output: 6  0  0  1  2  0
```

It should be pretty optimized and im not sure if you can make ist significant faster (idea-wise, probably you can optimize a few thinks of the implementation)

MfG Mike

Comment: what do you mean by `maximal suffix`?

Comment: When you have 3 elements "Abc" "CCbc" and "12bc", just "c" would be a suffix every elements has - but i think you wnat the suffix with the maximal possible length (in this case "bc")

Comment: I don't think I mean that. I mean `all the lcp between a list and all its suffixes`. Please see edit

Comment: I don't think i understand what you want. lcp of a list with itself will alwys result in the length of the list. 
And lcp of a list and the same list minus 1 element will be length  -1. ?
Perhaps  you cann add an example O(n²) Implementation ...

Comment: `lcp of a list and the same list minus 1 element will be length -1` is not true. `lcp [1;2;3] [1;2;3] = 3`, but `lcp [1;2;3] [2;3] = 0` which is `not length-1`. **it is minus the first element from the list, not the last element.** I have given an example about what are the suffixes of a list.

Comment: Ah sorry, i totally overread that. Now it makes much more sense :D

Comment: Yeah, the problem statement sounds simple and easy to overread, but actually complicated for O(n).